SSL issue when calling PowerBI API from Azure Function
I'm calling the PowerBI API (via the SDK) in an Azure Function (C# .NET 8 isolated, v4 on a Linux plan).
When I'm running this in development (on my own machine) it works perfectly.
After deploying this to Azure I'm getting a SSL error:

Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.`

It's happening on this line:
powerBiClient.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(workspaceId, reportId);

The function is in a VNET and as far as I can see (I have limited rights) the network is allowing all outbound traffic.
Did somebody see this behavior before? Or has any tips on how I can find the problem?

DNS Resolution for the api.powerbi.com from the function is ok
We can ping api.powerbi.com from the Kudu console
Checked for certificate issues. But exception is thrown even before certificate check is done


I'm getting the same issue - did you resolve this by any chance?

It's been a while, but if I remember correctly, the issue in the end was that delegated permissions on the app registration needed to be approved by an admin. Even if it says that it's not needed
